# Query with relation in Solr

Tags: python, solr, sunburnt

I have this situation:

```
{"product": {"name": "Name of Product",
             "categories": [{'name': 'Category 1'}, {'name': 'Category' 2}]}
```

This is the structure's resume of my solr document. When I'm going to search, I always will search for the name of the product and for the category. But, if I search for this product and `category = 'Category 1'`, I should return a json like this:

```
{"product": {"name": "Name of Product",
             "categories": {'name': 'Category 1'}}
```

I don't know the best way to do this. For now, my options are:

1. Make this final structure in the code;
2. Make two collections in Solr, Product and Category, and simulate a join to mount this final response.

I am really new in Solr, so I am kind of confused.

By the way, I am using sunburnt in my Flask application.

Answer (score 0):

Simulating a join with Solr is usually something I want to avoid, as that would require several roundtrips to Solr to fetch information. It's however a possible solution, but requires more application logic (I'd rather prefer using Solr for search and then looking up the information from a database backed store, if that's already available in the application in that case).

I have two suggestions to avoid the extra round trip:

1. If you only need the name of the category, define categories as a multiValued field containing the name of the category and nothing more. That will allow you to perform a query against the field, and will return the category names for the partciular product. If you only want the category that matched the query, you could probably use the highlighter functionality to tag it, although I don't have a very good solution for that (.. but is that really necessary?)
2. If you need more metainformation about the category (such as id, name, etc.), create two fields, one with the name you're searching for, and another field that's a serialized JSON representation of the category. That way you'll have the required data attached to the document, as well as a proper field to query.

Searching would be something like `product:Product categories:"Category 1"` or with edismax and a more flexible search: `q=Product Category 1&qf=product categories` - it depends on how you want the search to function.

The drawback with this solution is that if you change the name of a category, you'll have to reindex everything present in the category to get the updated name for each document. In practice, this is usually not hard to handle. Our production backend is backed only by Solr, and we reindex data if needed.